# List of Stablecoins built on Ethereum

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-design, tokens, stablecoins

What are some stablecoin projects built on Ethereum and how do they distinct between each other?

Answer (score 2):

Stablecoins - regardless of the platform on which they've been implemented - generally fall into three broad categories:

- **Centralised / IOU** : A centralised controller holds an asset and creates IOUs that can be traded back in for the asset at a later date.
- **Collateralised**: Coin is issued in response to collateral being pledged. Value is kept stable by various means.
- **Algorithmic** (also called Seigniorage Shares ): Value of the coin is kept stable by algorithmically expanding or contracting the supply of coins in circulation.

For details on how each of these types work, see a general overview, such as [this](https://blog.coinmarketcap.com/2018/11/16/stablecoin-overview-a-condensed-version/) CoinMarketCap blog post.

Below are few examples of each type in the Ethereum ecosystem. (The list isn't exhastive - this is just what I have in my notes.)

- Centralised / IOU

  - TrueUSD (ERC-20)
  - DGX Token (don't think this is ERC-20)
  - Gemini Dollar (ERC-20)
- Collateralised

  - DAI
  - Synthetix
- Algorithmic

  - Terra
  - Ampleforth
  - Basis